# Randomly extracting substrings of equal length from the main string

Tags: python, string, random

I have a string as follows.

```
str_main='ATGCAGCACTAGGCAGCACTATGAAGCACTATGCTGCACT'
len(str_main)
40
```

I want to extract three subtrings from `str_main` such that each substring contains 20 characters.

These substrings should start from anywhere in the main string and thus, there will obviously be an overlap between the subtrings.

I found some solutions but they do not provide random substring extraction from the main string.

Desired output might be:

```
substr_1='ATGCAGCACTAGGCAGCACT'
substr_2='CACTATGAAGCACTATGCTG'
substr_3='CACTAGGCAGCACTATGAAG'
```

They are randomly extraxted from the main string. I should be able to extarct as many string as I want as the overlap is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function and use it three times like this:

```
import random


def get_random_str(main_str, substr_len):
    idx = random.randrange(0, len(main_str) - substr_len + 1)    # Randomly select an "idx" such that "idx + substr_len <= len(main_str)".
    return main_str[idx : (idx+substr_len)]


main_str='ATGCAGCACTAGGCAGCACTATGAAGCACTATGCTGCACT'
print(get_random_str(main_str, 20))
print(get_random_str(main_str, 20))
print(get_random_str(main_str, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of slicing your string:

`str_main_1[:20]` or `str_main_1[2:22]`

Try out something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(str_main_1)):
    print(str_main_1[i, i+20])
```

Comment: Do you think It is a random slicing?

Comment: Define random. The above snippet will build all substrings of length 20 from your string.

Answer (score 1):

Since each substring must be 20 characters the maximum value for the lower bound of the substring is the length of the string minus 21 (indexing starts at 0 so we need to subtract 1 more since length is 1 based not 0 based)

```
lower_bound_max = len(str_main) - 21
```

Then you just need to generate random numbers between 0 and this value to get the lower band of your random slice and add 20 to get the upper band

```
import random

lower_bound_max = len(str_main) - 21
for _ in range(3):  # repeat 3 times
    x = random.randint(0, lower_bound_max)
    print(str_main[x:x+20])
```